# How to globally save a response from a POST request

Tags: node.js

```
var http = require('https');
var qs = require('querystring');
var request = require('request');

var appid = appid
var Oauth = Oauth
var Authorization = 'Basic' + ' '+ new Buffer(appid + ':' + 
Oauth).toString('base64');
var url = "https://example.com"

var options = {
host: url,
headers:{'Authorization' : Authorization,
"Content-Type": "application/json"}
};

request.post({
url:url,
headers:{'Authorization' : Authorization,
"Content-Type": "application/json"}
}, 
function(request, response){
console.log(response)
var body = JSON.parse(response["body"])
var token = body["access_token"]
//console.log(token)
return token

});
```

I want to be able to access the token globally. For example, I want to be able to print it in the line below.

```
console.log(token)
```

However, I get undefined. How do I save the token globally?

Note: I do receive the correct token in the earlier steps.

Answer (score 1):

Declare token variable globally and define or assign the value to token variable in POST request. And access it globally after that as well.

Below is the code snippet:

```
var http = require('https');
var qs = require('querystring');
var request = require('request');
var token;
request.post({
    url:url,
    headers:{'Authorization' : Authorization,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"}
}, 
function(request, response){
   console.log(response)
   var body = JSON.parse(response["body"])
   token = body["access_token"];
});
```

Comment: I still have the same error- prints "undefined" when I print "token" globally after that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save it on client site use browser sessionstorage() or localstorage() or you can store it server side which depends on what use